# Check whether $36^{36}+41^{41}$ a multiple of $77$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $$a=\frac{36^{36}+41^{41}}{77}.$$

Is $a$ an integer?

I know that:

- The last digit ofr $41^{41}$ is $1$.
- The last digit of $36^{36}=6^{72}$ is $6$.

How can I use this information to answer my question, or do I need another thing to help me?

Comment: Looking at the last digit of $41^{41}$ and $36^{36}$ tells you the residue mod 10. But what you need to find out is the residue mod 77.

Comment: you have to test if $$36^{36}+41^{41} $$ is divisble by 7 and 11

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about $41^{41}$ and prime numbers.

Comment: @dfeuer imean is prime number "not" and  prime number

Comment: $41^{41}$ is not a prime number.

Comment: @dfeuer sorry I mean 41 is a prime number so $41^{41}$ is divided by only 41 and 1

Comment: so a prime *power* then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hint: $36^{36}+41^{41} = 36^{36}+(77-36)^{41} = 77m+36^{36}-36^{41} = 77m-36^{36}(6^5+1)(6^5-1)$ and $6^5+1=(6+1)(6^3\cdot5+6\cdot5+1)$.

Comment: I guess this is based on the fact that $6^3⋅5+6⋅5+1$ is a multiple of $11$? Is there a way to see this or are we supposed to compute $6^3⋅5+6⋅5+1$ to complete the proof?

Comment: @Did, I just calculated it quickly. It equals $1111$.

Comment: Aaaargh... $\langle$ *Faints* $\rangle$

Comment: @Did A lazy method without computing: $$(6^5+1)^2\equiv2(6^5+1)\pmod{11}\implies (6^5-1)(6^5+1)\equiv 0\pmod{11}$$. But I guess fast mental computations are never harmful :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Hint?  I guess you left the 6+1 to the reader.

Comment: @Graphth, I left $\ldots=77m$ part too. :-)

Comment: By the way, calculating $6^3⋅5+6⋅5+1$ is not so hard: $6^3⋅5+6⋅5+1=(216+6)\cdot 5 + 1=222\cdot5+1$.

Answer (score 13):

Let $n=36^{36}+41^{41}$. Three elementary steps:

- **What happens modulo $7$:** Note that $36\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and that $41\equiv -1\pmod{7}$ hence $n \equiv 1^{36}+(-1)^{41}=1+(-1)=0\pmod{7}$.
- **What happens modulo $11$:** Note that $36\equiv 3\pmod{11}$ and that $41\equiv -3\pmod{11}$ hence $n\equiv 3^{36}+(-3)^{41}=3^{36}-3^{41}=3^{36}\cdot(1-3^5)\pmod{11}$. 
  Since $3^5=9^2\cdot 3\equiv (-2)^2\cdot 3=12\equiv1\pmod{11}$, $n\equiv 0\pmod{11}$.
- **And the Grand Finale:** Since $\gcd(7,11)=1$, $n\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ and $n\equiv 0\pmod{11}$ together imply (actually, they are *equivalent* to the fact) that $n\equiv 0\pmod{7\cdot11}$, QED.

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh If you haven't done anything with mod, then that severely limits your options for *any* divisibility problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for the $\equiv$s.

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh Why are you deleting your comments?

Answer (score -1):

> $\displaystyle{\large%
> a = {36^{36} + 41^{41} \over 77}.\quad
> \mbox{Is}\quad a\quad \mbox{an integer ?}\\[3mm]}$

$\large\mbox{Hint: Try these tests}$

1. $$
   7\ |\ 7777\ \mbox{because}\
   777 - 14=763\,,\quad 76 - 6 = 70\,,\quad 7 - 0 = 7\quad\mbox{and}\quad 7\ |\ 7
   $$
2. $$
   11\ |\ 8096\ \mbox{because}\
   809 - 6=803\,,\quad 80 - 3 = 77\,,\quad 7 - 7 = 0\quad\mbox{and}\quad 11\ |\ 0
   $$

WA yields

$a = 17284125074533757891391113841182593918679814596127517531883081101$

Comment: How on Earth are the facts that $7\mid7777$ and $11\mid8096$, and the decimal expansion of $a$, useful to solve this?